# Empty numeric keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, hybrid-mobile-app

In my Cordova App running on a iPhone Simulator, when I click on an input field with type="number" the numeric keyboard appears but it is not populated with any number.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: @rmaddy this is not a duplicate of that SO. I did not disable the keyboard in the emulator. It appears but without the numbers (see screenshot).

Comment: But the screenshot is exactly what is covered in the duplicate. The keyboard is not being displayed at all, just its input accessory view. Did you try pressing Cmd-K in the simulator?

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks, that worked. :)